# Windows Phone 7.1, Silverlight NUnit Project -template and Moq: TypeLoadException

Tags: nunit, moq, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

it's time to do some unit testing with MVVM Light ViewModels.

**Setup:**

- Visual Studio 2010 SP 1
- Windows Phone 7.1 SDK Release Candidate
- [Silverlight NUnit Project -template](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/05/01/silverlight-nunit-projects.aspx)
- Moq (4.0.10827 Final)

**Steps:**

1. Create a new MvvmLight (WP7) -project
2. Convert project to WP7.1
3. Create a new Silverlight NUnit -project
4. Reference WP7-project to Silverlight NUnit -project
5. Add a dummy method to the MainViewModel (f.ex. public string DoSomething())
6. Add a test that instantiates MainViewModel, calls the dummy method and asserts.
7. Run tests -> everything should work as expected
8. Add reference to Moq
9. Add second test method with some Moq. I simply copy-pasted this demo code from Moq's site:

   var mock = new Mock();

   // WOW! No record/replay weirdness?! :)
   mock.Setup(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"))
       .Returns(true)
       .AtMostOnce();

   // Hand mock.Object as a collaborator and exercise it, 
   // like calling methods on it...
   ILoveThisFramework lovable = mock.Object;
   bool download = lovable.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0");

   // Verify that the given method was indeed called with the expected value
   mock.Verify(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"));
10. Run tests.

This is what i get via NUnit runner at step 9:

```
SilverlightNUnitProject2.SilverlightTests.TestSomething:
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Action' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

**Question:**

What is going on here? Which part of my setup is failing and why?

**Update!**

I found a blog post related to this problem [here](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2010/07/26/unit-testing-nunit-a-wp7-project/). This inspired me to download and try the [exactly same version of Moq (3.1.416.3)](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/detail?name=Moq.Silverlight.3.1.416.3-bin.zip&can=1&q=) used in that article. And whaddayouknow? It works.

I'm not going to put this up as an answer, because i still don't know what's going on here. Original question still stands, i think.

Comment: Don't think MOQ will work in this case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724574/windows-phone-7-mocking-framework