# best mock library for windows phone 7 tests

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, testing, mocking

I am developing a windows phone 7 application and I want to create unit Tests for my application So which one is best mock library for .NET 3.0, .NET 3.5 and windows phone 7 application.

Answer (score 3):

There's no mocking frameworks for Windows Phone. See [Windows Phone 7 mocking framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724574/windows-phone-7-mocking-framework/4727949#4727949) for a explanation.

Comment: Interesting - did you see the update that Reflection.Emit is supported on Mango? Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I looked into porting Moq, but there's severe lacks for constructing mocking expressions, to it being worth the time.

Comment: I've just release an early version of a mocking framework for Windows Phone 7: http://moqalate.codeplex.com/  http://www.dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Introducing-%28probably%29-The-Worlds-Only-Mocking-Framework-for-Windows-Phone-7-%28WP7%29.aspx